# Make a list of Structs conform to a protocol SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

I have a custom protocol say

```
protocol CustomProtocol {}
```

and I have a custom struct say

```
struct CustomStruct: View, CustomProtocol
```

How can I make (CustomStruct, CustomStruct) conform to the CustomProtocol

I have a Custom ViewBuilder which has an init function,

```
init<views>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> TupleView<Views>)
```

Now I want only Views that conform to the `CustomProtocol` to be accepted

Example:

```
struct CustomStruct: View {
var views: [AnyView]

init<Views: CustomProtocol>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> TupleView<Views>) {
    self.views = content().getViews
}
```

I added an extension to tuple view for the getViews variable:

```
extension TupleView {
var getViews: [AnyView] {
    makeArray(from: value)
}

private struct GenericView {
    let body: Any
    
    var anyView: AnyView? {
        AnyView(_fromValue: body)
    }
}

private func makeArray<Tuple>(from tuple: Tuple) -> [AnyView] {
    func convert(child: Mirror.Child) -> AnyView? {
        withUnsafeBytes(of: child.value) { ptr -> AnyView? in
            let binded = ptr.bindMemory(to: GenericView.self)
            return binded.first?.anyView
        }
    }
    
    let tupleMirror = Mirror(reflecting: tuple)
    return tupleMirror.children.compactMap(convert)
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot. Tuples cannot conform to protocols. What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: I have a Custom ViewBuilder which has a init function, init<views>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> TupleView<Views>), Now I want only Views that conform to the CustomProtocol to be accepted

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: `init<Views: CustomProtocol>` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Nope, I tried this but it gives an error, (CustomStruct, CustomStruct) doesn't conform to CustomProtocol

Comment: Actually, I want to extract the list of views inside of the tupleview, but I only want to accept those views inside the viewbuilder that conform to the CustomProtocol

Comment: @Cristik [`TupleView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tupleview) is part of SwiftUI. I don't think they need to add details about it?

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: I think you need to "reinvent" [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder). See all those overloads of `buildBlock` that return `TupleView`? You need to rewrite them to accept a generic constraint of `MyProtocol` instead. That said, you can't really use anything from the protocol in `init`, so what is the point?

Comment: Yep, I cannot use them inside the init, but it will add a constraint for the user so that he/she can only add a view to the viewbuilder that conforms to the CustomProtocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to reinvent your own [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder):

```
@resultBuilder
struct MyCustomViewBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)> where C0 : View & CustomProtocol, C1 : View & CustomProtocol {
        ViewBuilder.buildBlock(c0, c1)
    }
    static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2)> where C0 : View & CustomProtocol, C1 : View & CustomProtocol, C2: View & CustomProtocol {
        ViewBuilder.buildBlock(c0, c1, c2)
    }

    // and so on... add every method in ViewBuilder here
}
```

In Swift 5.9+, you can write `buildBlock` using a parameter pack.

```
static func buildBlock<each Content>(_ content: repeat each Content) -> TupleView<(repeat each Content)> where repeat each Content : View & CustomProtocol {
    ViewBuilder.buildBlock(repeat each content)
}
```

Before Swift 5.9, `ViewBuilder` had overloads of `buildBlock` of up to 10 views (which is why you couldn't put more than 10 views in a `ViewBuilder`), so you needed to write 10 overloads of `buildBlock` if you want the same functionality as `ViewBuilder`.

Then you can do for example:

```
struct CustomStack<Views>: View {
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
    
    let views: [AnyView]
    let content: TupleView<Views>

    // note the change from @ViewBuilder to @CustomViewBuilder
    init(@MyCustomViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> TupleView<Views>) {
        let view = content()
        self.views = view.getViews
        self.content = view
    }
}
```

Now if you do:

```
CustomStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Text("World")
}
```

The compiler would complain that `Text` does not conform to `CustomProtocol`.