# SwiftUI. How to filter ViewBuilder childs?

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, viewbuilder

I'm very curios how `.swipeActions` of `List` view implemented

This is how `.swipeActions` looks like

```
List {
        Text("Test")
            .swipeActions {
                Button("Action1") {}
                Button("Action2") {}
            }
    }
```

`.swipeActions` accepts `ViewBuilder` as a content

The interesting part is If I add anything else then `Button`, it will be ignored.

```
List {
        Text("Test")
            .swipeActions {
                Button("Action1") {}
                Text("Test")
                Button("Action2") {}
            }
    }
```

`Text` is ignored here !

How to achieve this ?

I want to make custom View with similar functionality.

How to create ViewModifier that takes `ViewBuilder` as parameter and then filter everything except `Button` ?

Comment: SwiftUI uses its internal "magic" that you don't have access to. That said, you can make non-`Button`s *not compile*, using an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69357760/5133585).

Answer (score 0):

The `Text`s are technically not "filtered out" by `swipeActions`. As far as `swipeActions` is concerned, the `Text`s exist.

It is when the "backend" of SwiftUI (whatever is creating the actual `UICollectionView` cells from your `View` structs) sees these views, that the `Text`s get discarded. That code doesn't know how to deal with `Text`s.

A similar thing happens in `Menu`, `.tabItem`, etc. These only support a subset of SwiftUI views, but it still compiles if you write unsupported views in their view builders.

Obviously, you don't have access to the "backend" of SwiftUI, so you cannot do the same.

You can, however, disallow non-`Button`s at compile time, by writing your own version of `@ViewBuilder` that only builds `Button`s:

```
@resultBuilder
enum ButtonsBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<each L>(_ content: repeat Button<each L>) -> TupleView<(repeat Button<each L>)> where repeat each L : View {
        ViewBuilder.buildBlock(repeat each content)
    }
}
```

and have your modifier take a `@ButtonsBuilder` instead of `@ViewBuilder`. But unlike a `@ViewBuilder`, you cannot use `if`/`switch` and other control flow structures.